# R: Use (m?)apply with a function that returns a list as the argument to the function to be applied over?

Tags: r, list, apply, mapply

I have a function of two arguments `foo(a,b)`. As an input of this function, I was to use every row of the output of `combinations(10,2)` from the gtools library. I've tried to get it to work with `mapply` and I really had high hopes for `apply(combinations(10,2),1,foo)`, but everything that I've attempted throws the error "argument "b" is missing, with no default". How can I correct this without storing combinations(10,2) in memory and dividing it up? I suspect that I'm missing a trick with `Vectorize`.

For a simple reproducible example, use `beta(a,b)` in place of `foo(a,b)`.

What I very specifically **do not** want to do is anything like:

```
a<-combinations(10,2)
mapply(foo,a[,1],a[,2])
```

because I do not want to store combinations(10,2) in memory.

Comment: Do you need the output as below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we can use `do.call` with `mapply` or `Map`

```
do.call(mapply, c(FUN = foo, asplit(combinations(10, 2), 2)))
```

Or with `Map` (returns a `list`)

```
do.call(Map, c(f = foo, asplit(combinations(10, 2), 2)))
```

As a reproducible example, can use `beta`

```
do.call(Map, c(f = beta, asplit(combinations(10, 2), 2)))
```

Comment: After using ```asplit``` why do you need do.call? Shouldn't ```mapply``` be sufficient after ```asplit```?

Comment: @J.Mini `mapply` or `Map` expects the arguments to be specified as arg1, arg2, etc. i.e. in your case, a[,1], a[,2].  The `combinations` is a matrix and not a data.frame.  If it was a data.frame, the unit is column, but a matrix is a vector with dim, so the unit is just a siingle element.  So, Have to split with. `asplit` by column, and then use `do.call` so that Map considers each column as a unit argument

Comment: I understand now, but it's hard to put in to words. As I understand it, this ```asplit``` produces two lists, but you can't use said ```asplit``` as a single argument of ```mapply``` because ```mapply``` can't handle two lists as one argument. This means that you have to give the two lists in question to ```mapply``` indirectly. ```do.call``` is the best way to do this because it can take a list of lists as an argument and feeds the lists in the list to ```mapply``` as individual lists.